# Do range hood inserts with rear exhaust exist?

Tags: kitchens

I may try to fabricate an under-cabinet range hood, and would use a range-hood insert with integrated baffles and lighting, so fabricating just the "shell".

All of the inserts I've found so far have a top-mounted circular exhaust vent, which wouldn't work in our case without major expensive cabinetry work. Are these inserts also made with a rear-mounted rectangular exhaust vent (approx 4x10)?

Answer (score 2):

I have an older Bosch unit that was sold with both inserts, however:

Standard fans usually have pretty weenie capacities and putting a 90 degree bend will seriously affect their flow. This is why cheaper, low capacity hoods only come with straight inserts. Ironically, many expensive, snazzy looking, hoods have miserable performance.

High capacity hoods with beefy fans tend to be a lot more money, but will have the overhead (ha ha!) to accomodate bends and longer duct runs.

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace it with an over the range micro wave that would vent out the wall? Instead of using just the hood. That's what I did and it freed up more counter space. You then have both in one.